# SignalR scaleout in Azure for high frequency scenario

Tags: azure, signalr, scalability

From my reading on SignalR scaleout in Azure, the recommended way is to use Azure ServiceBus as a backplane. But in the same time there is limitation on using backplane for high frequency messaging.

In terms of Limitation chapter in [Scaleout in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr), I would characterize my app as something between chat and real-time game. Any tips how to implement SignalR scaleout (in Azure) for this?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this or solve it yourself? What was the decision you made? We're more or less in the same boat with scaleout for a chat like app. We're using Redis cache though and it clearly seems to be limitation.

Comment: The project for which I was considering using SignalR died already (it used custom developed scalable polling using WCF on Azure worker roles). We still use client polling in another project with Azure AppService but it is stateless - we don't need server affinity. You can have a look at Firebase as an alternative to SignalR

Comment: Thanks @eXavier! Will check out firebase.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the # of topics (queues) that you use to increase throughput and scale up

Comment: But there is explicitly stated: **High-frequency realtime (e.g., real-time games): A backplane is not recommended for this scenario.** in [manual](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr).<br>Could you please provide some more details or/and performance tests?